# What does "that" in "remember that" refer to?

Tags: meaning

In *Promising Young Woman (2020)*, Cassie arrives at Al's bachelor party posing as a stripper, drugs Al's friends, and takes Al upstairs. She handcuffs him to a bed:

> Cassie: I don't think they can hear you. And even if they could,
> they're all passed out by now. 'Cause if there is one thing
> I learned at Forrest, it's how easy it is to slip something into a drink.
> You'd think they'd remember **that**, especially Joe.

What does "that" in "remember that" refer to?

Does it could mean she thinks Joe has slipped something into someone's drink before,
or that someone had done it to him before.

(or)

Is Cassie saying Al Monroe friends don't remember that they got drugged by her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cause if there is one thing I learned at Forrest, it's **how easy it is to slip something into a drink**. You'd think they'd remember **that**

Cassie is saying that one would expect that they (Al's friends downstairs) would remember **how easy it is to slip something into a drink** (and therefore be more cautious, which they obviously were not).